# How to toggle more than two images based on which radio button is selected?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery code that someone suggested to me earlier in order to toggle the visible image based on which radio button is selected.
The first image has a static position in order to preserve its parent height and subsequent images are absolutely positioned and stacked on top of the first one and each other.
The code I'm using works well if there are two images and two radio buttons, but what if the user decides to add more images and radio buttons? How do I edit this jQuery code to work with 3, 4, 5, or more images and radio buttons?

```js
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
  $(".image-container img:nth-of-type(2)").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.image-container img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.image-container img:not(:first-of-type) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=2&w=350&h=150" class="img-fluid" alt="image1">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1&w=350&h=150" class="img-fluid" alt="image2">
  </div>
  <form id="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input id="black" type="radio" checked="checked" name="color">
    <label for="black" title="black"></label>
    <input id="gray" type="radio" name="color">
    <label for="gray" title="gray"></label>
    <!-- other form inputs and buttons go here after the radio buttons -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: when adding code to OP use `<>` to create a demo

Comment: you want to show and hide depending on radio button meaning select first show first and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add value attribute to the radio buttons like shown below:

```
    <input id="black" type="radio" checked="checked" name="color" value="1">
    <label for="black" title="black"></label>
    <input id="gray" type="radio" name="color" value="2">
    <label for="gray" title="gray"></label>
    <input id="gray" type="radio" name="color" value="3">
    <label for="gray" title="blue"></label>
```

Then in the JQuery, access the value of selected radio button for the code to show/hide images based upon the value. Example selector:

```
    $(".image-container img:nth-of-type("+this.value+")")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify all the images separated by comma (,)

```js
<script> 
      $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
          $("selector1,selector2,...").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I need something that will work dynamically, based on how many images and input buttons user adds to the page through back-end.